# If with Find not working as intended

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm very new to VBA and have created a chart based on the Macro Recorder in Excel 2007. I'm having some trouble with an If statement that I expected to find the value of **`FALSE`** in a cell range and change the color of a marker in my chart. I'm not getting the desired results, but all of the markers are changing to the Else condition. Here is the snippet for reference:

```
Dim rSeries As Range
Dim MyChart As Chart

Set rSeries = Sheets("Data").Range("I24:I39")
Set MyChart = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("PT_Schedule").Chart
With MyChart
    If rSeries.Find("FALSE") Then
        .SeriesCollection(8).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(8).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Else
        .SeriesCollection(8).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(8).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End With
```

Can any one explain why any cell value of **`FALSE`** is not meeting the criteria and what should the code be changed to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a link `siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/` which will guide you on how to use `.Find` :) If you are still stuck then we will take it from there :)

Comment: I understand now why the entire collection is changing. I think I understand the .Find functionality. I have used the link you provided to determine (after some tweaking) that my error isn't in the find, but in the .SeriesCollection() instead. That is why the entire collection is changed instead of the single point. Is there a way to identify a single point within the collection and modify the coloring on the chart?

Answer (score 0):

the method Find() returns a Range, not a Boolean. 
You should verify if the range returned is not null (Nothing in VBA)

```
If Not rSeries.Find("FALSE") Is Nothing Then
```